# The template specified for component AppComponent is not a string

Tags: angular, webpack, angular8, angular-webpack

*disclaimer: Yes, I saw that there are more "The template specified for component AppComponent is not a string" related questions but none of them describes the specific problem I'm experiencing.*

I get this runtime error when I compile without AoT in *ng build*:

```
Uncaught Error: The template specified for component AppComponent is not a string
```

This error actually make sense because in the generated bundled code (main.ts) I see:

```
template: __webpack_require__(/*! raw-loader!./app.component.html */ "../node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js!../Scripts/app/app.component.html"),
```

while in a new Angular app I see:

```
template: __webpack_require__(/*! ./app.component.html */ "./src/app/app.component.html")
```

Somehow the *raw-loader* gets added as a loader to my .html files.

Now maybe it's important to mention that i'm migrating my webpack 4 AngularJs project to Angular 8. BUT When I debug my webpack build I see no rule that its *test* contains *.html* and a *loader.* that contains *raw-loader*.

[Debug picture of loader rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP9fV.png)

**So my loaders rules doesn't affect this raw-loader addition to app.component.html**

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

app.component.html:

```
 <div></div>
```

I'll appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: post `AppComponent.ts`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downgrading *raw-loader* from 2.0.0 to **1.0.0** fixed this issue.

First I learned from angular source code that they added raw-loader to templateUrl by default in [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/bd55bf01d5b7d95227b36c1fe11d9e6f2df19de8) since Angular 8.
Then it's later used in [here](https://github.com/angular/ngtools-webpack-builds/blob/master/src/transformers/replace_resources.js#L60).

raw-loader 2.0.0 generated:

```
/***/ "../node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js!../Scripts/app/app.component.html":
/*!********************************************************************************!*\
  !*** ../node_modules/raw-loader/dist/cjs.js!../Scripts/app/app.component.html ***!
  \********************************************************************************/
/*! exports provided: default */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = ("<div>\r\n    app componenets works!\r\n</div>\r\n");

/***/ }),
```

And raw-loader 1.0.0 generates:

```
    /***/ "../node_modules/raw-loader/index.js!../Scripts/app/app.component.html":
/*!********************************************************************!*\
  !*** ../node_modules/raw-loader!../Scripts/app/app.component.html ***!
  \********************************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = "<div>\r\n    app componenets works!\r\n</div>\r\n"

/***/ }),
```

which is good.
Angular needs module.exports to be string here.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using

```
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', // or whatever filename
```

instead of   `template: './app.component.html',`

Comment: I'm using it, I'll add the snippet of code to my question.

Comment: you are probably missing an ending quote in the html file , can you post `app.component.html` too ?

Comment: I posted it also

Comment: What is `kibana` &  `ng-view` this is not valid HTML

Comment: I simplified app.component.html and it still happens, I updated my answer with the current app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

use to be

templateUrl: require('./app.component.html').default

..raw-loader > 1 , because export as default.

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

firstly close the browser and then reopen it
after that type (  npm i  ) into the terminal, after completion of npm installation.
then type ( ng serve).